# Converting Content Page to Navigation Page in Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I created a Content Page named MainList.xaml. Now my main page isn't a navigation page since it deals with setting the App up but I want MainList.xaml to be a navigation page. The problem is, when I try:

```
MainList mainListPage = new NavigationPage(new MainList());
```

I get the error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'Xamarin.Forms.NavigationPage' to 'SalApp.views.MainList'

How would I go about converting it into a navigation page? There doesn't seem to be an option to even create a navigation page. In the App.xaml file, I can make MainPage.xaml a navigation page but I don't know why MainList doesn't have the same privilige.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you're creating an instance of `NavigationPage` that wraps `MainList`, to the type returned will be a `NavigationPage`

```
NavigationPage navPage = new NavigationPage(new MainList());
```

Comment: I feel so dumb for not noticing that but thank you anyways.

Comment: @SamuelMungy You are supposed to accept answers if it's correct when you create a question.

Comment: I honestly never knew that's what the tick was for. Thank you for informing me.